# Why am I getting StaleObjectStateException when using Session.merge

Tags: hibernate

My application is multi-threaded so when using natural keys for objects even though I check if an object with said natural key already exists there is always the possibility that the object is created just after I checked for its existence, causing a StaleObjectStateException when I save my new object.

I thought this could be resolved using Session.merge() but it still gives me the aforesaid error

I have tried reading up on this, but havent found something that clarifies this clearly, most examples talk about Merge checking database but always show a detached instance of object in same function confusing the issue.

i.e

```
try
{
      session = HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
      Widget widget = new Widget();
      widget.setData(data);
      widget.setKeyFromData(data);

      //Look in db for widget with same id and return it merged with data in widget or
      /create new object ?
      widget = session.merge(widget);

      session.close();
}
catch(StaleObjectException soe)
{
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a version in hibernate as merge uses this field to determine recent record.